# Is there a way to prevent CMake from enforcing the toolchain layout when using CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN?

Tags: android, cmake

- I am using CMake 3.8 or newer
- I am using a custom toolchain file to configure for Android
- **Using the NDK is not an option**

As the title suggests, I have a custom Android toolchain I'd like to use, rather than the NDK. The problem is that when setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Android` and specify `CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=<path-to-my-toolchain>`, CMake seems to enforce the layout of said toolchain. It's like the user is not trusted to completely configure their own Android toolchain?

Currently, I am forced to set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Generic` or `Linux` in my toolchain file to get past the configuration stage, and I do not really like that solution.

Is it really not possible to use a standalone Android toolchain without having CMake enforce the layout (without modifying the CMake Android modules, of course)?

### CMake error output

The first thing it complains about is not having a sysroot:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/Platform/Android-Determine.cmake:74 (message):
  Android: The standalone toolchain directory specified by CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN:
    /home/<path-to-toolchain>
  does not contain a sysroot with a known layout.  The file:
    /home/<path-to-toolchain>/sysroot/usr/include/android/api-level.h
  does not exist.
```

If I fix the error above, the next in line is this:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler-Standalone.cmake:16 (message):
  Android: No '*-gcc' compiler found in CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN:
```

This error is caused by the fact that CMake expects a `bin`-folder with a gcc toolchain in the main toolchain folder.

Comment: Can you post any output from CMake showing how the setup fails? You may just need to set a few more variables, but without seeing the output, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @CraigScott I updated my post with some error outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [CMake implementation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler-Standalone.cmake), it would seem that it does make assumptions about the toolchain layout. Apart from the requirement stated in the [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN.html#variable:CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN) that there must be a `sysroot` subdirectory below the nominated `CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN` directory, the implementation assumes there will be matches for `${CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN}/bin/*-gcc${_ANDROID_HOST_EXT}`, where `_ANDROID_HOST_EXT` will be `.exe` on Windows and empty otherwise. It then continues on with a bit more logic, but if the toolchain is gcc-based, it should be fine.

Looking at the implementation a bit more deeply, if you set the `ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN` environment variable rather than the `CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN` CMake variable, it bypasses the sysroot check (more accurately, the check for the `api-level.h` file at a path under the sysroot). If you do this, then after that, CMake will still try to determine the API level by first looking for `<sysroot>/bin/clang` and querying it if found, or else looking for the `api-level.h` file again. If your toolchain doesn't have `<sysroot>/bin/clang`, then you can set the *undocumented* and *internal* CMake variable `_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN_API` to the API to prevent CMake from looking for and requiring `api-level.h`. You wouldn't normally want to rely on something internal like this, since it could change with any future CMake release, but that would be the price of what you are wanting to do.

If you don't want to rely on internal details, then setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Linux` and manually setting up the toolchain details like any other non-Android build is likely to be your best option. You will then need to set up all relevant compiler and linker flags, etc. just like any other cross-compiling situation, since it won't trigger any of CMake's automatic handling for Android.